# How to install Suggests dependencies of a package

Tags: apt, dependencies

If I want to install a package and its Suggests dependencies, I run:

```
$ sudo apt-get --install-suggests install <package name>
```

However, if `<package name>` is already installed, and not all Suggests dependencies are installed, 'nothing' happens... those remaining dependencies remain uninstalled. Is there a solution for this, beyond writing code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the advanced searching features of `aptitude`. The following will install packages suggested by `network-manager`:

```
aptitude install '~Rsuggests:^network-manager$'
```

From the aptitude HTML documentation:

> *?reverse-depType(pattern), ~R[depType:]pattern*
>
> depType may be either “provides” or one of the dependency types given
>   in the documentation of ?broken-depType. If depType is not present, it
>   defaults to depends.
>
> If depType is “provides”, matches packages whose name is provided by a
>   package version matching pattern. Otherwise, matches packages which a
>   package version matching pattern declares a dependency of type depType
>   upon.

Comment: Aptitude user manual:
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/

Please add a link to "aptitude HTML documentation" in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

A less standard solution:

```
$ wajig installsuggested network-manager
```

Usage info:

```
$ wajig installsuggested --help
usage: wajig installsuggested [-h] [-r | -R] [-y] [-n] [-d DIST] [-s | -t]
                              package

Install a package and its Suggests dependencies

positional arguments:
  package

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -r, --recommends      install Recommend dependencies (Debian default)
  -R, --norecommends    do not install Recommend dependencies
  -y, --yes             skip 'Yes/No' confirmation prompts; use with care!
  -n, --noauth          do not authenticate packages before installation
  -d DIST, --dist DIST  specify a distribution to use (e.g. testing or
                        experimental)
  -s, --simulate        simulate command execution
  -t, --teach           display commands to be executed, before actual
                        execution
```